# Can't print all the results all at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to create a script which will fetch the title and the description of products from this ***[webpage](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/%7E/3M-Cubitron-II-Cut-Off-Wheel/?N=5002385+3290927385&preselect=8710644+3294059243&rt=rud)***. In it's landing page there is a single product. However, when you take a look at the left sided area, you will notice a tab titling `17 products`. I'm trying to grab their `title` and `description` as well. The tab named `17 products` in reality does nothing as the 17 products are already within the page source.

I can fetch all the 18 products in the following manner. I had to use `print` twice to print all 18 products. If I append the results and print all them together, the script will look messier.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/~/3M-Cubitron-II-Cut-Off-Wheel/?N=5002385+3290927385&preselect=8710644+3294059243&rt=rud'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")

    product_title = soup.select_one("h1[itemprop='name']").text
    specification = soup.select_one(".MMM--tabHeader:contains('Product Details') + .tabContentContainer").get_text(strip=True)[:30] #truncated for brevity
    print(product_title,specification)

    for additional_link in list(set([item.get("href") for item in soup.select(".js-row-results .allModelItemDetails a.SNAPS--actLink")])):
        res = s.get(additional_link)
        sauce = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        product_title = sauce.select_one("h1[itemprop='name']").text
        specification = sauce.select_one(".MMM--tabHeader:contains('Product Details') + .tabContentContainer").get_text(strip=True)[:30] #truncated for brevity
        print(product_title,specification)
```

How can I print all the title and description of products all together?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question. You want to print all of the title and descriptions together, but you don't want to append them to a list, because the script would be messy?

One option is to use a dict instead of a list. Define a dict up at the top of your code after the imports: `products = {}`, and swapping out your print statements with `products[product_title] = specification`

Afterwards, you can use the pprint package, which I believe comes with python, to neatly print the dictionary object, like so:

```
import pprint
some_random_dict = {'a': 123, 'b': 456}
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(stuff)
```

Replace `some_random_dict` with `products`

If you're concerned with neatness, I would also refactor this bit into a seperate function:

```
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    product_title = soup.select_one("h1[itemprop='name']").text
    specification = soup.select_one(".MMM--tabHeader:contains('Product Details') + .tabContentContainer").get_text(strip=True)[:30] #truncated for brevity
```

Maybe something like this:

```
def get_product(sess, link):
    info = {}
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    product_title = soup.select_one("h1[itemprop='name']").text
    specification = soup.select_one(".MMM--tabHeader:contains('Product Details') + .tabContentContainer").get_text(strip=True)[:30] #truncated for brevity
    info[product_title] = specification
    return soup, info
```

Your code would then look like this:

```
products = {}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'
   soup, product_info = get_link(s, link)
   products.update(product_info)
   
   for additional_link in list(set([item.get("href") for item in soup.select(".js-row-results .allModelItemDetails a.SNAPS--actLink")])):
        sauce, product_info = get_link(s, additional_link)
        products.update(product_info)
```

Having the same piece of code pasted around in multiple places is something that should always be avoided. Refactoring that bit into a separate function will help readability and maintainability in the long run.